# undefined reference и статическая библиотека с stdlib

Tags: c++11, static

Есть самописная статическая библиотека,
в ней я использую функции из `math.h` и `stdlib.h`.

Но при линковке появляются ошибки

> undefined reference to cos и undefined reference to strcpy

поясните почему подобное может происходить